# drupal 7 access control set in content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, controls, rules

So I am trying to set per node access based on a checkbox field in the content type.  I would like to use Rules to set the access depending on what is selected in the checkboxes.

For example I create a new page and I have theoptions of check a box for A, B, C,D, E and I can select as many as I want. Each letter represents a role so a person that has the role A, D will see any page with those checked off.

I need help setting up the rule in Drupal 7 and I do not have access to install any other modules.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your needs can be met totally by using the *Nodeaccess module*, here at:

https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

This module has all that you want.

Comment: I did mention in my question I don't have access to add a new module, I have to figure this out only using the Rules module.

Thanks though.